# After wake from sleep, windows moved from desktop on external display to desktop on MacBook display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

After my MacBook wakes up, I find it's moved all the windows from the desktop on the external display, to the desktop on the MacBook display. This is extremely annoying.

I understand completely that the MacBook thinks the external display is not attached anymore because perhaps it's too slow to wake up. But moving the windows between desktops, which are a group, is just annoying because I'm using desktops to organise themes of work that I'm grouping together on purpose. So when the MacBook wakes up, I find that all the windows from both displays are now on the MacBook display, mixing everything together.

If Apple wants to do this, why not move the entire desktop that was previously on the external display to the MacBook display but keep the grouping the same?

The way I see it, things are grouped together. Windows are inside a desktop, which is a group of windows, and each screen has a number of desktops, which basically groups multiple desktops onto a particular screen.

So is there a way to tell macOS to move the entire desktop with all its contents intact to the MacBook display, instead of moving the windows between different desktops, causing the chaos I'm talking about?

Comment: Are you using "Displays have separate Spaces"? I'd have to assume not - in which case each Space is a pair of displays where one has been removed. That should move all windows from each Space back to the primary *on that Space*. If 'separate spaces' was on, then the entire Space would move as a unit to the primary, as Spaces don't have an affinity to a display.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice this message at first. Yes I'm using "Displays have separate spaces". The issue I have with this behaviour isn't that when a display isn't detected it moves the space to a different display. It's that it's moving windows from one desktop to another, instead of just moving the entire desktop as a group to a different display. Which would still keep the windows grouped on a single desktop, even if it was moved to a different physical display

Comment: I can confirm that this is extremely annoying. A workaround is to wait for the external display to fully wake and connect before logging in. Unfortunately, it still messes up some windows but not that often.